# Create lambda expression with reflection for LINQ2SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda, expression

I have this class

```
class abstract EntityBase
{
    public abstract int Id {get; set; }
}
```

Now, i change a little bit my linq2sql generated class for user table (set override for Id)

```
public partial class User: EntityBase, INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ...
  public override int Id {...}
  ...
}
```

Than, i have another template helper class with this function

```
public static T SingleOrDefault(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> func)
{
    System.Data.Linq.DataContext oDataContext = null;
    T retData = GetAll(out oDataContext).SingleOrDefault(func);
    if (retData != null)
    {
        retData.CurrentDataContext = oDataContext;
    }
    return retData;
}
```

And i use it like this

```
Helper<EntityBase>.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == 3);
```

And i get : Class member ***EntityBase`2.Id is unmapped***. The problem is that it is using the Id from EntityBase not from the User class so my question is how can i construct the corresponding lambda expression for this so that it can refer the Id from the user class.
Hope i was clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Surely you'd need to call `Helper<User>.SingleOrDefault` to start with. Why can't you just do that?